# how to create a registry key without using system() in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, registry

how to create a registry key without using system()/.bat/.reg  in c/c++??

Answer (score 7):

Use [RegCreateKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724842(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: actually, i want to add a right click option in windowsXP for my vc++ app(win32)...
suggest if i use a external .bat file (.reg) and call it.
OR
ANY SIMPLER WAY TO ACHIVE THIS????

Comment: Simpler than `RegCreateKey()`? Consider taking vacations asap.